# Epson printer - print two images horizontally from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, printers, epson

I downloaded the ios (swift) sdk for epson epos2 printer and I integrate with my application without any problem. Now I can print the images or texts vertically one by one. But my problem is I want to print two image and one text horizaontal. For this format I tried `addpageArea(x,y,width,height)` `addpagebegin()`, `addpageEnd()` and I tried with `addPagePosition(x,y)` also. These methods also print in vertical format only.

Comment: why is the actual problem with the e.g. CoreGraphics PDF Context? that could help you to create standard printable content for every kinda _air printers_, you don't need to support specific printers one-by-one in an iOS app; furthermore the PDF Context is well documented on __[Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1666286-cgpdfcontext)__, and probably you could find thousand tutorials as well online.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.i check my printer model is not not compatible device list.what to do

Comment: there is a few __epos__ printers which supports _air printing_ (even Epson has such receipt printers for iOS), but Apple does not list any of them, so you can't rely in their list in this case; you need to find models on your own.

Comment: Thanks for guidance.i have own printer.model name  : EPSON TM-m30 model.

Comment: my thoughts maybe not relevant in resolving your problem :) but basically if we go back to your OP and determine your specific device (TM-m30) does not support connecting via Wi-Fi, it is likely that it does not support the _AirPrint_ feature in generic at all; so __the next question is__: could you send generic PDF content to the device via the Epson SDK? if yes, I would recommend to fall back that solution and build up the PDF via the PDF Context of CoreGraphics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168306/discussion-between-abhishek-thapliyal-and-krutarth-patel).